# Sum of squares of distances between all vertices in tree

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given the adjacency list of unweighted undirected graph without cycles, calculate sum of squares of distances between every two vertices. How to do this fast? (programming task)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say divide and conquer will probably work acceptably here.

To begin with, starting with the adjacency list, I'd build a properly linked up graph. So, a collection of vertex objects, with a list of pointers to edge objects, and a collection of (the same) edge objects, each with a pair of pointers to its vertices. This'll cut down on a bunch of list searches that would just waste time.

Then, pick an edge, $\{v, w\}$. When you delete that edge from the graph, you get two connected components, each with a special vertex, either $v$ or $w$. Now, the set of paths in the whole graph can be broken up into $3$ collections: those which stay in the $v$ connected component, those which stay in the $w$ connected component and those which cross between components.

First, solve the problem for the two smaller connected components (and remember that if there is just one vertex by itself, then it has a sum of $0$).

Then build a list of distances between $v$ and all the vertices in that component, and then do the same for $w$. Now, you don't need a full list, with an entry for each vertex, you just need a list of the number of distance 0 vertices, distance 1 vertices, distance 2 vertices etc. If you're smart, you should be able to reuse these lists created for the smaller connected components to speed up your calculation of this list.

Then, given the two lists, call then lv and lw, you can calculate the sum of the lengths squared of the paths that cross between the components, its $\sum_{i, j} lv[i]*lw[j](i+j+1)^2$ (if you precalculate a list of squares of integers, or memoize them when you calculate them, this should be pretty cheap).

There might be quicker ways to do this, but this should be pretty useful for most purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Your graph is a tree and plenty of efficient structures exist to store and manipulate a tree.

The distance, in this case, is given by the number of steps we need to reach the least common ancestor. Moreover, there is a recursive pattern hidden in there: what happens if we add a leaf to our tree? How the sum of the squared distances distances change if we give a father to the root of our tree? If you are able to find the answers, you already have an efficient algorithm.